# Software for solving for equations

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac

I have been wondering if there is a software that can allow me to solve for equations and understands a latex like written equation. So for example:

If I write `v_f^2= v_i^2 + 2a`d and say that `V_f is 0 v_i` is 10  and a is -4.5. It should automatically rearrange the equation and solve for d.

I don't mind a little change in syntax, but I would like it to comply with the format one uses for writing equations in latex.

Regards,
Ted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LaTeXCalc](http://latexcalc.sourceforge.net/) program seems to do something along the lines of what you're looking for, you'll want the cygwin version to run it in Windows, and they say it's fairly limited.

*Edit*
Looks like this has already been answered on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219121/is-there-a-calculator-with-latex-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

There is [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Math.html) at the web, that could help in solving equations. Wolfram also have [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) solution.

Comment: I don't think WolframAlpha.com supports LaTeX. Mathematica probably does.

Comment: Actually it does http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2010/09/30/talk-to-wolframalpha-in-tex/.

Comment: I take that back!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) instead of Mathematica. It is free and has ncurses and GUI interfaces (wxMaxima).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can Maxima take LaTeX input?

Comment: I do not know if you can input LaTeX but you can output LaTeX with the tex() function. See: http://www.hippasus.com/resources/symmath/maximatypeset.html